# irreducibility conjecture

Tags: polynomials, conjectures

I tried to prove that every polynomial of the form

$f(m,n) := m\cdot x^{n-m}+(m+1)\cdot x^{n-m-1}+\cdots+(n-1)\cdot x+n \quad \text{with} \quad 0 < m < n$

is irreducible over the rationals for all integers m and n.

I made some progress using the enestroem-kakeya-theorem and could show
 that $f(m,n)$ never has a linear factor. If I did not make any mistake,
 I even proved that $f(m,n)$ is irreducible if its degree is 100 or less.

But I did not find a complete proof even for the case $m=1$.
 Perhaps, someone has an idea.

What could be useful : Any root $u$ of $f(m,n)$ has the property
 $\frac{n}{n-1} < |u| < \frac{m+1}{m}$